# Trigger an input action from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to trigger an action of a input event from a javascript code. I need to trigger that action using swipe gesture in javascript is inside the  is algo a function of other javascript library

Here is the action i want to trigger the class is "pt-trigger" data-animation you choose which transition you want and "data-goto" you choose the page you want to go all this is other javascript library

```
<input id ="flechanegra10" type="image" src="img/flechaabajo.png" class="pt-trigger"  data-animation="3" data-goto="-1" width="63" height="63" />
```

I wonder if all the stuff that is happening inside the "input" it can by trigger by a javascript conditional if is diffY > 0 it detect the swipe up or down:

```
// sliding vertically
        if (diffY > 0) {
          // swiped up
          label.textContent = "up";
          console.log("swiped up");
        } else {
          // swiped down
          label.textContent = "down";
          $link = $('a:first');
          $("input").select(function();
          console.log("swiped down");
        }  
      }
```

Comment: *I want to trigger an action of a input event from a javascript code* Huh?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no 'onswipe' event available on HTML. Nevertheless you can implement your own using Javascript, here is a good reference resource: https://css-tricks.com/simple-swipe-with-vanilla-javascript/

Comment: Yeah, i'm using a javascript code here is it:    
  if (diffY > 0) {
          // swiped up
          label.textContent = "up";
          console.log("swiped up");
        } else
          $link = $('a:first');
          $("input").select(function();
          console.log("swiped down");
        }  
    But html still new to me so i want to trigger this
 <input id ="flechanegra10" type="image" src="img/flechaabajo.png" class="pt-trigger"  data-animation="3" data-goto="-1" width="63" height="63" />
using the conditionals